# VBA Complex multi delimiter split

Tags: vba, excel, split, delimiter

I have a complicated split I need to do in VBA excel. I have a column of cells containing the strings like this example:

```
Name1 (10%), Name2 (50%), Name3, Name4 (40%)
```

I need to split this string and return each value to specific cells on the worksheet that are non adjacent. Example:

```
Name1  - Cell B1
10%    - Cell C1
Name2  - Cell M1
50%    - Cell N1
Name3  - Cell X1
(blank)- Cell Y1
Name4  - Cell AD1
40%    - Cell AE1
```

The main problem I'm having coming up with a solution to this is that the strings can be any length.

They may contain:

1-10 names,

each name **may** or **may not** have a percentage after it

I'm still doing research and testing, but I can't find a real viable solution. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated

Comment: where do you need to split it, and do you need to strip out the % figure?

Comment: Why can't you split on the comma? Then if needed you can use some other function (`Left` comes to mind...) if you need to remove the percent scores, too.

Comment: Otherwise yes, please clarify where you need it split, and then what you are trying to do with it. As currently stated, it's really not clear what you intend to do.

Comment: Seems there is no shortage of people willing to help. There are potentially easy points to be had here!

Comment: I've added an example of the effect I'm hoping for in the question. Sorry for being unclear.

Comment: OK so that makes sense. Can you show us what you have tried so far, even if it doesn't work?

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying something right now that delimits on the "," and then  finds the size of the resulting array. Based on array size I can _somehow figure out how to return values to the appropriate cell?_ From there I can strip the ")" and delimit again on the "(" to get a 2 long array containing either Name, percentage or Name, or nothing. I'm not sure this is viable logic, but I'll post the code in a few minutes when I debug it. Everything else I've tried so far has just been crap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way

```
Sub SplitNames()

    Dim vaNames As Variant
    Dim vaPct As Variant
    Dim i As Long

    'split on comma
    vaNames = Split("Name1 (10%), Name2(50%), Name3, Name4(40%)", ",")

    'loop through the name/pct pairs
    For i = LBound(vaNames) To UBound(vaNames)
        'split each on open paren
        vaPct = Split(vaNames(i), "(")

        'Write the name to a cell
        Sheet1.Range("A1").Offset(0, (11 * i) + 2).Value = vaPct(0)

        'If there's a pct, write it to a cell
        If UBound(vaPct) >= 1 Then
            Sheet1.Range("A1").Offset(0, (11 * i) + 3).Value = Replace(vaPct(1), ")", vbNullString)
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Just did a test drive, this works like a charm. The original question is about a column of values so I just embedded the whole thing in a For loop that is `For X = 1 To lastRow` Thank you so much, this was a far more elegant solution than what I was attempting on my own. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

OP requires VBA but someone else may accept an alternative, hence:

Find `space` Replace with `,`
Find `(` Replace with `nothing`
Find `),` Replace with `nothing`
Find `)` Replace with `nothing`

Text to Columns delimited with `,` (Treat consecutive delimiters as one not checked)

Insert columns to suit.

Alternative to Find/Replace:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",","),"(",""),"),",""),")","")
```

Copy down to suit, select the column, Copy, Paste Special, Values then proceed with Text to Columns.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub SplitRoast()
    Dim x() As String
    x = Split(Replace(Replace(Replace _
        (Replace(Range("A1").Value, ")", ""), "(", ""), ", ", ","), " ", ","), ",")

    Range("B1").Value = x(0)
    Range("C1").Value = x(1)
    Range("M1").Value = x(2)
    Range("N1").Value = x(3)
    Range("X1").Value = x(4)
    '(blank)- Cell Y1
    Range("AD1").Value = x(5)
    Range("AE1").Value = x(6)

End Sub
```

Comment: This won't work. The example I gave in the question is just and example. Not all strings will have blank values in them. Some will have many blank values. Because of this you **can't** consider the **length** of your array `x()` to be a constant